# How to render html content within label tag using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on asp.net mvc. I have a javascript variable like,

```
var note="&lt;strong&gt;&lt;em&gt;&lt;span style='color:#ed1c24;'&gt;Hai&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/em&gt;&lt;span style='color:#ed1c24;'&gt;Welcome&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/strong&gt; ";
```

I need to display as a html with in the label so i tried it like,

```
$('#lblNote').html(note);
```

but it doesnt render the html content and it shows the html tags as it is like,

```
<label id="lblNote"><strong><em><span style=""color:#ed1c24;"">
    Hai</span></em><span style=""color:#ed1c24;"">
    Welcome</span></strong> </label>
```

please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

There are two syntax errors in your code, 1. change the wrapping quotes to single quotes or escape them 2. and remove the line-breaks or concatenate the strings.

```
var note = '<strong><em><span style="color:#ed1c24;">Hai</span></em><span style="color:#ed1c24;">Welcome</span></strong>';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VsGqg/

---

You should replace the characters:

```
$('#lblNote').html(note.replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>'))
```

Comment: @undefined: I modify my question please have a glance on it.

Answer (score 1):

escape your double quotes like this

```
var note="<strong><em><span style=\"color:#ed1c24;\">
Hai</span></em><span style=\"color:#ed1c24;\">
Welcome</span></strong> ";
```

Comment: I modify my question please have a glance on it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var note="<strong><em><span style='color:#ed1c24;'>Hai</span></em><span style='color:#ed1c24;'>
Welcome</span></strong> ";

$('#lblNote').html(note);
```

Comment: :I modify my question please have a glance on it.

Answer (score 1):

Format your string properly. note should be

```
var note="<strong><em><span style=\"color:#ed1c24;\">
Hai</span></em><span style=\"color:#ed1c24;\">
Welcome</span></strong> ";
```

Comment: I modify my question please have a glance on it.